# How to load .mat files into Spyder quickly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, spyder

I'm importing large .mat files into Spyder; however, it takes roughly a minute until it's done. Is there a way to more efficiently load them in without the long time delay? Here is how I've been doing it so far:

```
import scipy.io as sio
import pandas as pd

cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)

data = pd.DataFrame(sio.loadmat(os.path.join(cwd + '/Data/VER_005.mat')).values()).iloc[7]
```

The dataframe only contains two columns, but the length is 2,215,727.

Comment: `loadmat` is the only standard (in `numpy`, `scipy` or `pandas`) loader that handles the earlier (non HDF5) .mat files.  What's the relative time of the `loadmat` part versus the `DataFrame` construction?  I also doubt if `Spyder` is relevant.  This looks just like a regular Python script.

Comment: As hpaulj mentioned, you can use `h5` or `h5py` library for faster reads. Alternatively, `loadmat` function has optional input `variable_names` that specifies what parts of the .mat structure get loaded. Of course, this is helpful only for struct so might not be helpful to you.

Comment: Loading HDF5 format `.mat` files is harder than `loadmat` compatible ones.  Search SO for relevant questions if you want to try that.